# node_modules - running the local copy instead of the global one

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a node package that installed globally. With my current env set up, there are some conflicting issues but I was able to find a solution but I would like to change the bundled.js file for that library.

Instead, what I would like to do is install that package to the local project's directory and make the changes there only. However, when I try to do this, it seems like when I run the node module, it references the globally installed version of that package?

Is there a way where I can specify, when I run the package, to run off the local copy rather than the global one? Or am I going to have to delete the global one?

Comment: What do you mean by "run the package"? If you're running a bin command such as `mocha` or something that's installed by npm, what's the output of `which mocha`. If it's in `/usr` or similar, it's because the global module path is higher up in your `$PATH` than `node_modules/.bin`.

Comment: @Ryan so it's the `truffle` package. When I `truffle init`, I got an error that I googled and found a solution for. But I want to test that solution in the local `truffle` package, so I `npm install` `truffle` locally, go to the node_modules folder to the file to update the line (per googled result) but then after when I try to `truffle init`, I get the same error.

I assumed, that was due to the command referencing the global truffle install but I am realizing now that may not be the case and that I am misunderstanding how NPM works...

Answer (score 1):

From your project folder, to execute your local install:

run `./node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js init`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the global `node_modules` folder: `C:\Users\username\node_modules`